# Perl - remove first word in a string with regexps

Tags: regex, string, perl

I'm new to both Perl and reg-ex's, and I'm trying to remove the first word in a string (or the first word in a line in a text file) , along with any whitespace that follows it.

For example, if my string is `'one two abd123words'`, I want to remove `'one '`.

The code I was trying is: `$line =~/(\S)$/i`;
but this only gives me the last word.
If it makes any difference, the word i'm trying to remove is an input, and stored as $arg.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove the first word of each line use:

```
$line =~ s/^\S+\s*//;
```

**EDIT** for a explanation:

```
s/.../.../            # Substitute command.
^                     # (Zero-width) Begin of line.
\S+                   # Non-space characters.
\s*                   # Blank-space characters.
//                    # Substitute with nothing, so remove them.
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the explanation, I've found tons of websites detailing how individual regular expression commands work, but very few explaining how to actually combine parts.

Comment: why, when I try to print this, do I just get a `1` (bool?), as opposed the the string? I'm just using  `print $line =~ s/^\S+\s*//;`?

Comment: @ImprovedSilence: Print in other instruction: `$line =~ s/^\S+\s*//; print $line;` or use `r` switch, as: `print $line =~ s/^\S+\s*//r;`

Answer (score 2):

You mean, like this? :

```
my $line = 'one two abd123words';
$line =~ s/^\s*\S+\s*//;
# now $line is 'two abd123words'
```

(That removes any initial whitespace, followed by a one or more non-whitespace characters, followed by any newly-initial whitespace.)

Answer (score 2):

In one-liner form:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's{^\s*\S+\s*}//' file.txt
```